# Ислючить дублирование товаров

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Создаю интернет-магазин, сейчас реализовываю "Подробный просмотр" товара. Товар успешно отображается с необходимыми атрибутами, но при "просмотре" другого товара, предыдущий не удаляется и накапливается в памяти, т.о. форма подробного обзора продуктов содержит все товары, которые я добавил с помощью запроса.

Это класс Detail

```
namespace App.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Detail 
    {
        private List<DetailLine> lineCollection = new List<DetailLine>();

        public void AddItem(Product product)
        {
            DetailLine line = lineCollection
                .Where(g => g.Product.ProductId == product.ProductId)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (line == null)
            {
                lineCollection.Add(new DetailLine
                {
                    Product = product
                });   
            }

        }
        public IEnumerable<DetailLine> Lines
        {
            get { return lineCollection; }
        }
    }
public class DetailLine
    {
        public Product Product { get; set; }
}
}
```

Это DetailController

```
namespace App.Web.Controllers
{
    public class DetailController : Controller
    {
        public ViewResult Index(string returnUrl)
        {
            return View(new DetailIndexViewModel
            {
                Detail = GetDetail(),
                ReturnUrl = returnUrl
            });
        }
        private IProductRepository repository;
        public DetailController(IProductRepository repo)
        {
            repository = repo;
        }
        public RedirectToRouteResult AddToDetail(int productId, string returnUrl)
        {
            Product product = repository.Products
                .FirstOrDefault(g => g.ProductId == productId);

            if (product != null  )
            {
                GetDetail().AddItem(product);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
        }



        public Detail GetDetail()
        {
            Detail detail = (Detail)Session["Detail"];
            if (detail == null)
            {
                detail = new Detail();
                Session["Detail"] = detail;
            }
            return detail;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Список товаров]
[image: Желаемый результат]
[image: Дублируемый результат]

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему, закрыв сессию в DetailController:

```
public Detail GetDetail()
        {
            Detail detail = (Detail)Session["Detail"];
            if (detail == null)
            {
                detail = new Detail();
                Session["Detail"] = detail;

            }
            else {
                Session.Abandon();
            }

            return detail;
        }
    }
}
```

Однако стоит ли использовать таким образом передачу товаров в подобных решениях?